# Python: Does the user need to download library?

Tags: python-3.x

noobie question here. I've been writing a program in python3.5.1 and I'm managing pretty well with the built in libraries like tkinter but I'm starting to want to use libraries that aren't built in with python3.5.1.

The problem with this is that as far as I can tell if I use a library that isn't built into python the users of my program will have to download the library as well. Which would be a major pain in the ass for  a lot of users. Am I correct in assuming this? Is there a way to work around this?

I don't mind having to download the stuff myself, but I would like my users to be able to run my program with just basic python3.5.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Users need to download your program.  And many Python programs do consist of multiple source files.  In some cases you can simply include the external libraries you use with the files you're shipping to the user.  But this may not work well if the libraries contain compiled C code and you're targeting multiple platforms.

Alternatively, you can simply document which packages users need to install to use your program.  They can then use whatever system package manager they have, or PIP, etc.